# mocha test timeout on fs.exec npm install gulp jshint

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, yeoman, gulp

I am using mocha and below piece of test timeouts, any idea why?

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    this.timeout(4800000);
        console.log('running npm install; bower install on fixtures');
        exec('npm install; bower install', { cwd: path.join(__dirname, 'fixtures') }, 
        function(error) {
            if (error) { console.log('Error: ' + error); }
            done();
            console.log('npm done');
        });
    });
});

it('should pass jshint', function(done) {
    this.timeout(24000);
        exec('gulp jshint', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) { console.log('Error: ' + error); }
            expect(stdout).to.contain('Finished \'jshint\'');
            expect(stdout).to.not.contain('problems');
            done();
        });
});
```

But if i remove `beforeEach`, it works fine. If i have the `beforeEach` it doesn't hang on `beforeEach` (`npm done` is logged), but hands on `exec('gulp jshint')`. Any idea how `beforeEach` could effect that?

If i do `gulp jshint` manually it runs quickly under 2 seconds.

```
$ gulp jshint
[12:00:44] Using gulpfile ~/website/test/.tmp/gulpfile.js
[12:00:44] Starting 'jshint'...
[12:00:44] Finished 'jshint' after 457 ms
```

Actually the project is here [generator-emberfs](https://github.com/eguneys/generator-emberfs) if you want to try, it's under `test/test-creation.js`.

Comment: The most likely culprit here is `done` isn't being called, can you confirm that your `exec` callback is hit?

Comment: But why, is something wrong with the `exec` command, or `npm install` command?

Comment: I have no idea why, that's why I am asking you to check whether the callback is being hit...

Comment: @James So `done` is not called and it timeouts, it's also not about `npm install` but `gulp jshint` command test after that.

Comment: @James, it's now more than that see the edit please.

Comment: On a side note do you think it is a good idea to use a testing framework to see if your code passes jshint? Why don't you lint your code BEFORE you run actual tests?

Comment: @m90 I don't jshint for that, it's a yeoman generator and it tests the generator output if it passes jshint. I simplified the example.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to re-run `npm install` / `bower install` before every test anyway, surely it would make sense to do this once at the beginning of the test run?

Comment: @James I don't know how to do that, it shouldn't take long after the first time, since node_modules folder won't get deleted after the first `npm install` so it's not a big deal i guess.

Comment: You would use `before` rather than `beforeEach` which means it would run once for that particular test suite, not that it would make much of a difference here just that it would mean you could rule it out the `npm/bower install` call being part of the problem.